# Knex generating wrong query

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm making a query like this with Knex.

```
  const query = knex
  .select('ue.username', 'ue.permission', 'ue.status')
  .from('user_entity as ue')
  .join('device_entity as de', function () {
    this
      .on('de.username', '=', 'ue.username')
      .andOn({'de.deleted': ''})
      .andOn({'de.token': token})
      .andOn({'de.uid': uid});
  })
  .where({'ue.deleted': ''})
```

Node.js Console shows just that.
in token condition for some reason generates with (´) and replacing (´ ´) with (" ") the query works normally. But I don't understand why he generates the SQL with (´ ´)

```
select `ue`.`username`, `ue`.`permission`, `ue`.`status` 
from `user_entity` as `ue` 
inner join `device_entity` as `de` 
    on `de`.`username` = `ue`.`username` 
    and `de`.`deleted` = `` 
    and `de`.`token` = `C0AbKXv2ffWS7w` 
    and `de`.`uid` = `F8F9C9A8-06CC-40E4-AE8E-75FE7FA6BB57` 
where `ue`.`deleted` = ''
```

How SQL should be...

```
select `ue`.`username`, `ue`.`permission`, `ue`.`status` 
from `user_entity` as `ue` 
inner join `device_entity` as `de` 
    on  `de`.`username` = `ue`.`username` 
    and `de`.`deleted` = ''
    and `de`.`token` = 'C0AbKXv2ffWS7w'
    and `de`.`uid` = 'F8F9C9A8-06CC-40E4-AE8E-75FE7FA6BB57'
where `ue`.`deleted` = ''
```

---

a query with inner join but Knex generates in "Inner Join in condition (and)" with (´ ´) instead of (" ").

Answer (score 0):

`on` clause basically parses everything into column names, so all your values wrapped with `` ` ``, which is for mysql identifier such as table name or column name.

If you use typescript, or javascript IDE that supports parsing typescript syntax like vscode, you can check out type definitions for `.join()`.

```
interface JoinClause {
    on(raw: Raw): JoinClause;
    on(callback: JoinCallback): JoinClause;
    on(columns: { [key: string]: string | Raw }): JoinClause; // <--------
    on(column1: string, column2: string): JoinClause;
    on(column1: string, raw: Raw): JoinClause; // <-----------------------
    ...
}
```

As you can see, string parameters are `column*`. If you want to add condition according to non-column value, use should pass `Raw` value via `knex.raw()`.

```
knex("user_entity as ue")
  .select('ue.username', 'ue.permission', 'ue.status')
  .join('device_entity as de', (j)=> (
    j
      .on('de.username', '=', 'ue.username')
      .andOn({'de.deleted': knex.raw("?","")})
      .andOn({'de.token': knex.raw("?","iMoENdVC5hSUwr")})
      .andOn({'de.uid': knex.raw("?","TPB4.220624.004")})
  ))
  .where({'ue.deleted': ''})
```

[Knex Playground](https://wirekang.github.io/knex-playground/#a25leCgidXNlcl9lbnRpdHkgYXMgdWUiKQogIC5zZWxlY3QoJ3VlLnVzZXJuYW1lJywgJ3VlLnBlcm1pc3Npb24nLCAndWUuc3RhdHVzJykKICAuam9pbignZGV2aWNlX2VudGl0eSBhcyBkZScsIChqKT0+ICgKICAgIGoKICAgICAgLm9uKCdkZS51c2VybmFtZScsICc9JywgJ3VlLnVzZXJuYW1lJykKICAgICAgLmFuZE9uKHsnZGUuZGVsZXRlZCc6IGtuZXgucmF3KCI/IiwiIil9KQogICAgICAuYW5kT24oeydkZS50b2tlbic6IGtuZXgucmF3KCI/IiwiaU1vRU5kVkM1aFNVd3IiKX0pCiAgICAgIC5hbmRPbih7J2RlLnVpZCc6IGtuZXgucmF3KCI/IiwiVFBCNC4yMjA2MjQuMDA0Iil9KQogICkpCiAgLndoZXJlKHsndWUuZGVsZXRlZCc6ICcnfSk=)